# Visual Studio refactoring variable type

Tags: c#, visual-studio, refactoring

Is it possible to refactor a variable type just like its name in Visual Studio?

Comment: Please show us some sample code, so we can envisage the kind of refactoring you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: Like i have a varible in an abstract class that is an int. And I want to change every instance of that variable to double even in child classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately with a vanilla Visual Studio instance there isn't a way to refactor a variable type. it would be almost impossible for automation to do it, at least if you mean change a string to an int for example.

Consider this refactor

```
        string str = "I'm a string";

        //Refactor to int would be

        int str = "I'm a string";
```

The above would then cause an error you would have to manually fix. however when using var you can refactor to explcit types.

```
        var str = "I'm a string";

        //Refactor to Explicit would be

        string str = "I'm a string";
```

You can however right click a variable and click find all references which will perhaps be helpful in at least identifing all instances where you will have to rename and clicking each will take you straight to them.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get is to find all references to a variable and then go through every occurence of variable and change sorrounding code to match new datatype (if necessary).

[image]

Comment: apologies looks like we both added this at the same time, have an upvote

Comment: @Mike No problem :)